# Django template inheritence

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

In my django app i have a base.html template as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>

    {# ----------------- STATIC FILES -------------- #}
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{% static 'images/tab_logo.ico' %}"/>
    {% block site_css %}
        <link href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="{% static 'core/css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    {% endblock %}
    {% block extra_css %}{% endblock %}
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
{% block navbar %}
    <!-- START  NAV -->
    <nav role='navigation'>
        <a data-page="home" id="home" class="active" href="/">Home</a>
        <a data-page="blog" id="blog" href="{% url 'blog' %}">Blog</a>
        <a data-page="contact" id="contact" href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact Us</a>
        <a data-page="about" id="about" href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a>
    </nav>
    <hr>
{% endblock %}
<!--start container-->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span9">
            <div id="content">
                <br>
                {% block content %}{% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--end container-->
<hr>
{% include 'core/footer.html' %}
{% block javascript %}
        <!-- Grab Google CDN's jQuery, with a protocol relative URL; fall back to local if offline -->
        <script src="{% static 'core/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'core/js/skin.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
{% block add_js %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to make separate template files for blog,about,contact

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}
{% block add_js %}
    <script>
    $(document).ready(skinchange('blog'));
    </script>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h1 style="text-align: center;font-size: 32px;">BLOG</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Now in the index page(nav bar home active), when i click on the blog link (Blog) redirection to localhost:8000/blog/ is done.When this page is loaded i want to change the class of nav a for blog to be active so that the style of the page is changed as per my css.For this i am executing a jquery script ->  $(document).ready(skinchange('blog'));

where skinchange is a function in skin.js

```js
'use strict';
function skinchange(page) {
                page  = typeof page !== 'undefined' ? page : 'home';
                var link = $("nav a");
                $("body").removeClass().addClass(page);
                link.removeClass("active");
                var d = document.getElementById(page);
                d.className +="active";
            }
```

for some reason on new page loading the class attribute of the nav links remains same as the base.html.The jquery script is not executing.
Can anyone help me what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: You have `block add_js` in the parent template but `block _addjs` in the child.

Comment: Typo error my bad.But still cant seem to get the jquery script working

Comment: I think there may be necessary to write function in jquery initializattion.May be $(document).ready(function(){ skinchange(page) }); would work